Barnum Effectus
What should replace the "?" in the following figure?


The image depicts

 The zodiac signs in order from Aries at the top going clockwise to Pisces.

If we

 Extract letters from their names, given the numerals, we get S T E N L O L O ? T N A C. If we anagram this we get CONSTELLAT?ON. So we're missing the letter I. The zodiac in 9th position corresponds to the 13th zodiac sign - Ophiuchus, and the only I in Ophiuchus is in 4th position. So the question mark should be replaced by IV.

Here's a diagram illustrating how I extracted the letters:

   I first noticed that Gemini looked identical as the roman numeral for "2" (in the diagram ofc), and the placement of it (it happens to be the the third Zodiac sign in order), helped me figure out that they were arranged in a clockwise order starting with Aries at "12 o'clock" and finishing with Pisces at "11 o'clock". Ophiuchus (which is not part of the usual 12 Zodiac system and is referred to as the "forgotten constellation") is also conveniently placed between Scorpio and Sagittarius given that (if included) is the 9th Zodiac sign in order.  Here's a link to the Zodiac signs for those interested.


Can you please explain your answer further for someone who is unfamiliar with the knowledge?

@BenjaminWang Further explanation added now

Nice! Thank you for explaining the subtle hint. And the title makes sense too.
